# Need to remove all nines from this array

Tags: java, collections

I need a method which will remove all nines from "myList". Anything helps, thank you.

```
public class ArrayListPractice 
{
    ArrayList <Integer> myList = new ArrayList <Integer>();
    public ArrayListPractice() 
    {
        myList.add(6);
        myList.add(2);
        myList.add(7);
        myList.add(3);
        myList.add(12);
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(9);
        myList.add(9);
        myList.add(3);
        myList.add(5);
        myList.add(9);
    }
}
```

Comment: O(n) problem since it's an array. Just loop through and if the value is 9 remove it.  Sorting only makes it worse

Comment: why not simply not add them in the first place?

Comment: Switch to base 9 instead of decimal. This gets rid of all 9s in O(1).

Comment: `for(Iterator i=list.iterator();i.hasNext();if(i.next().equals(9))i.remove();` now it do backwards to reduce the copy.

Answer (score 2):

Start always with the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
final Integer nine = Integer.valueOf(9);
while (myList.remove(nine)) { }
```

remove returns true if the list contained the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> indexWithNine = new ArrayList<int>();
for (int i=0; i< myList.length; i++){
  if (myList.get(i) == 9)
     indexWithNine.add(i);
}
for (int i=indexWithNine.length-1; i=0; i--)
{
  myList.remove(indexWithNine.get(i));
}
```

Comment: just use listIterator and scan backwards (`previous()/hasPrevious()`)and then remove()

Comment: You're right that would be much more simple Thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add( 9 );        
myList.removeAll( list1 );
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this: It will remove all occurrence of 9 from your ArrayList myList.

```
myList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(9));
```

*myList before : [6, 2, 7, 3, 12, 1, 9, 9, 3, 5, 9]*

*myList after:  [6, 2, 7, 3, 12, 1, 3, 5]*

Comment: Interesting, learned something.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do.

```
public List removeNines(List myList){
    Iterator itr = myList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        if(itr.next() == 9){
             itr.remove();
        }
    }
    return myList; 
}
```